# Make element to take 100% of visible empty space without JS

Tags: css

So... How I do something like this with CSS only? Watch red element, it scales not scrolls:
[image]

Currently it works via JS, I catch onscroll and update size of the element according to calculated free space.

This is how it works now:
https://codepen.io/bswan-the-decoder/pen/OJPVxZj

```
<div class="header">
   Header
</div>
<div class="header-spacer">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="page">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
   Footer
</div>
```

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 500;
}


.footer {
  min-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  left: 0px;
}

.page {
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #AAA;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F66;
  left: 10px;
  top: 105px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```
let header = document.querySelector('.header');
let footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
let sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
let header_spacer = document.querySelector('.header-spacer');
header_spacer.style.height = header.clientHeight+'px';

document.addEventListener('scroll',(event)=>{
   let height = window.innerHeight - header.clientHeight - 35;
   let scroll = this.scrollY;
   if(scroll+window.innerHeight+footer.clientHeight>=document.body.clientHeight)
   {
       height = (height - (
       (scroll+window.innerHeight+footer.clientHeight) 
       - document.body.clientHeight));
   }
   sidebar.style.height = height+'px';
});
```

This my new layout:
https://codepen.io/bswan-the-decoder/pen/wvBapvV

```
<body>
  <div class="header">

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar_holder">
      <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_holder">
      <div class="page"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">

  </div>
</body>
```

```
body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-height: 80px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.footer{
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.content{
  grid-area: content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar page";
}

.sidebar_holder {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.page_holder {
  grid-area: page;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 105px; /*how to make it (header height+20px) ?*/
  height: 100px; /*How to make it (100vh - header height - visible height of footer)?*/
  background-color: #F66;
}

.page {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #AAA;
  margin: 25px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;

}
```

Update:

@Roddy - I tried but my knowledge is lacking so there was nothing of use pruduced by me.

Comment: Did you attempt to solve this with css? Can you share your attempt?

Comment: What code you use

Comment: Links to external sites are not helpful because questions on StackOverflow need to remain valid and reproducible over a long period of time (many years), and the code on those linked pages is probably going to change in the meantime.

Comment: @connexo got you. Well, will put some code in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

To fill out the whole space with a div, you can use `ViewHeight` and `ViewWidth` units like:

`vw` and `vh` takes the percentage of the screensize and applies it,
100vw means 100% of the width

```
    .whole-area {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background: orange;
    }
    <div class="whole-area">
    <span>Text</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: This will scale to screen height, not free space on screen.

Comment: What do you mean 'on free space'? The element needs to be in the highest hirachy of the document. Otherwise you need use some tricks like `position: absolute`

Comment: Check out gif I provided(and now CodePen too). Can you see how element scales itself depending if footer in the frame or not. With 100vh it will always have height equal to screen height.

Comment: So you want that the red div takes all remaining space, is it correct? Your question in not clear to me. Should it be in the background? How do you want it to behave?

Comment: Checkout this CodePen  https://codepen.io/bswan-the-decoder/pen/OJPVxZj
and check how it works. Currently it need JS to work but I want pure CSS solution.
Size of red dive should be between 100vh - header_height and 100vh - header_height - footer_height depending on our scroll position and how much of footer is visible